# Changing object from external file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am learning Vue and before that I have some experience working with React.

As, I move on comprehending the basics of vue, I sort of compare things with JS

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
   <HelloWorld msg="Below This we will inclue our To-do task list"/>
    <p>{{msg}}</p>
    <Todos :toDoItem="todos"/>
  </div>
</template>

import Todos from "./components/todo.vue";
let todo = 
  {
    name: "Rohit",
    title: "Full Stack Developer",
    completed: true
  }

export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    Todos
  },
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "hello",
      todos: todo
    };
  }
};
```

We are passing the props here to child component and changing it using method

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <div class="main-class">
      <p>{{toDoItem.title}}</p>
      <input type="checkbox" v-on:change="markComplete">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

  <script>
export default {
  name: "toDoItem",
  props: {
    toDoItem: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
 method: {
  markComplete() {
   this.toDoItem.complete = !this.toDoItem.complete
   }

};
</script>
```

This is where I am unable to comprehend many things.

**Question 1:** Based on my understanding of `this`, shouldn't it point to  a global space and hence this should be undefined?

```
 markComplete() {
   this.toDoItem.complete = !this.toDoItem.complete
   }
```

**Question 2:** In react we can't change props passed to a child object probably? but here we are changing the props? Also, In general, if we declare a object in another file **(app.js)**, can we change it to in another file **(someApp.js)**?

Answer (score 1):

All methods in a Vue instance are bound to the instance so that `this` works properly.

You should not be changing props. Here, you are changing a member of a prop -- `toDoItem` is a prop, and `complete` is a member of it -- which is not controlled, but you still should not do it. You should instead [emit an event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) that the [parent handles](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events).

Your `markComplete` should be in the parent, since it owns the data being manipulated. It would look like:

```
markComplete() {
  this.todos.complete = !this.todos.complete;
}
```

In the child, the method would be something like

```
toggleComplete() {
  this.$emit('toggle');
}
```

And the parent would use [`v-on`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) to handle the toggle event:

```
<Todos :toDoItem="todos" v-on:toggle="markComplete"/>
```

This way all the code that manipulates data owned by a component happens within that component. Nobody calls anybody else's methods or modifies their data.

I think you intend for `todos` to be an array of items, and probably want to [`v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for) over them, having one child component for each item, but that's another issue.

I cannot answer your last question about objects declared in different files, because I don't understand it. It is not unusual to import objects and modify them, generally. As I mentioned, though, Vue components should be the only ones to modify their own data.

Comment: Roy, thanks for answer. Can you please make it slightly more detailed. Like what do you mean by **member of props** and an example of how  we should do it in general? (going through the link you shared) 
Also, If you could add on.
**In general, if we declare a object in another file (app.js), can we change it to in another file (someApp.js)?**